# Will Naruto have a Kid?

Tags: naruto

In Naruto movie 4, during the ending scene

> The priestess says that she needs to give her powers to the next priestess. And asks Naruto's help with this matter. But what did she mean by that? Did she mean it in the context "Make a new priestess with me?" or more in the context "Once the time comes can you help me transfer my powers?".

[**Video of the scene I'm referring**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bCA-5fm0DI0)

Comment: I doubt that they would make such innuendos ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, I shouldn't comment so fast :D.

> Then she asked Naruto if he would help **(indirectly asking if he will father her child)** to everyone's shock, which a misunderstanding Naruto, happily agreed to.

Source: Narutopedia

However, it never happened.

Comment: damn fillers =\

Comment: made for a funny moment though :p, Still wondering. Did it not happen because the movie is set to another time line or any other specific reason to it? or is it just never mentiond after anymore ?

Comment: @Dimitrimx: As Hashirama Senju (lol) mentioned, it's a filler. It's just like a parallel-universe.

Answer (score 3):

I legitimately doubt that anything serious was meant by that, or even came of it.

Naruto's character has always been to help others out where and when they need it, but in this case, he didn't pick up on the subtext like Rock Lee, Kakashi and Sakura did.

If nothing else, there won't be a child between him and that priestess.  Considering that, in canon...

> ...he has *two* children with Hinata:  Boruto and Himawari.